# Histogram Pyplot y axis scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I'm having trouble scaling my Y axis histogram by frequencies rather than by counts (which is what I have now). I want it to go from 0 - 1 rather than 0 - 10000. Because it's a histogram, I can't simply divide by 10,000. Any suggestions?

This is my code & graph
[image]

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def hash(old, new, rho):
    length = 8  # length of nonce
    nonce = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)]) 

    str_old = str(old)                            #convert int blocks to strings
    str_new= str(new)

    hash_input = str_old + str_new + nonce         #concatenate 

    bitarray = ' '.join(map(bin,bytearray(hash_input,'utf8')))   #change input string to bits


    length = len(bitarray)                           #get bit length (out of 256)

    correspondence = 2**(length-rho)-1               #correspondnece for bit length 

    inp = hash_input.encode('utf-8')                 #encode concatenated string of blocks & nonce
    hex_int = hashlib.sha256(inp).hexdigest()        #put encoded into hash

    digest = (int(hex_int,16))                            #convert digest to integer


    if digest <= correspondence:
        return True
    else:
        return False    



def b_hist(old, new,rho):
    results = []
    for i in range(10000):
        if hash(old, new, rho) == True:
            results.append(1)
        else:
            results.append(0)
    
    #EXPERIMENTAL HISTOGRAM PLOT
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.hist(results, bins = 2, rwidth = 1, align='left') 
   #plt .set_ylim([0,1])
    plt .title("Problem 5")
    plt . xlabel("Value")
    plt . ylabel("Frequencies of success/failures")
    plt . draw()
    
    
    #THEORETICAL PMF PLOT 
    successRate = 0.5**rho
    failureRate = 1 - (0.5**rho)
    
    x = [0, 1]
    y = [failureRate, successRate]
    
    plt. scatter(x,y)
    plt .show()

def main()
    b_hist('hello world ', 'rur rur', 3)
```

Comment: It's not possible to run your example, would you post a complete running script?

Comment: @heltonbiker sure, i think it should work now?

Comment: `hash_mine` is not defined

Comment: @PaulH youre right, im sorry. I just added it

Answer (score 1):

From the [`pyplot.hist` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) we see that `hist` has an argument `normed`, which is an alias for `density`:

> `density` : boolean, optional
>   If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., the area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1. This is achieved by dividing the count by the number of observations times the bin width and not dividing by the total number of observations. If stacked is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.

You may use this to get a normalized histogram.

If instead you want that the counts sum up to 1, independend of the bin width, you can simply divide the histogram by its sum. This would be a two step process

```
hist, bins_ = np.histogram(results)
freq = hist/np.sum(hist)
plt.bar(bins_[:-1], freq, align="edge", width=np.diff(bins_))
```

The same can be achieved in one step by supplying an appropriate weight

```
hist, bins_ = plt.hist(results, weights=np.ones_like(results)/np.sum(results) )
```