# How to measure probability from probability density function

Tags: matplotlib

Documentation says if normed=True it returns the probability density function. I want to know the difference between probability density function and I also want to know that how I can calculate probability in this case? Will it be the probability of finding value in bin? How equal and non equal bins will effect this probability?

```
`x=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,10,10,4,40,40,40,4,5,5])
plt.hist(x,bins=10, normed=True)`
```

Comment: This might be a bit too broad of a question. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237743/histogram-pyplot-y-axis-scaling/43238399#43238399) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660271/pdf-plotting-concern/51660842#51660842) helps. Of course the respective wikipedia articles on [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and [pmf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) might equally help.

Comment: Does it mean I need to find area under bins to measure probability?

Comment: Would you like to plot the pmf? Or would you like to read the pmf from a plot of the pdf?

Comment: i didn't get . I am confused about how to get probability. I read questions related to plt.hist on stackoverflow but didn't get my answer

Comment: One cannot give a complete tutorial on statistics here. But within a limited scope one may try help you solve a problem. So for that I asked you to specify if you want to plot the probability mass function or if you want to plot the probability density function and find a way to read the values of the mass function from it?

Comment: I want to calculate probability not the probability density function nor probability mass function.

Comment: There is only (1) frequency (2a) pmf (2b) pdf. 
You need to decide for one. Let's ask differently: In how far does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237743/histogram-pyplot-y-axis-scaling/43238399#43238399) not help? It would plot the pmf for you. What do you not like about the result?

Comment: I want to calculate probability. Because probability density function can exceed the value of 1 whereas probability can not. I expect that the height of the bins should be such that there sum should be equal to 1.

Comment: So you are talking about a probability mass function. Again, why does the linked answer not help?

Comment: In the linked answer they are using np.histogram function . But I want to use plt.hist. Secondly this function returns 3 values, n,bins and patched. When we don't assign any value to normed n gindicates height of bars or number of samples in each bar. but when normed=True its returns some floating values. I tried to sum sum them but they are not equal to one means they are not indicating probability. In the linked answer they used n/(len(x)`dbin), what is dbin?

Comment: I edited the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43238399/4124317) with a solution where you only need one call to `plt.hist`, although that is probably a bit harder to grasp. When using `normed=True`, the **integral** equals to 1. `dbin` in the link means the bin width.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Can you please mention one more thing if I use plt.hist(x,bins=30,normed=True). Then on y-axis I get floating values what they indicate? Like when I don't mention normed then values on y-axis indicate the number of samples in each bin

Comment: If you use `normed=True` the  y-values are the values of the probability density function. That is why `normed` has been replaced in newer versions of matplotlib by the name `density`.

Comment: got it. thanks alot